# Should I use var in Java 10?

Tags: java, java-10

Given that I can't use `var` for *non-denotable* types (Nulls, Anonymous classes, Some Single Method Class and most importantly Intersecting Types), am I better off not using it for better readability and consistency (given that it's only for *local* types)?

I kind of feel that it would be abused:

```
var a = someObj.getSomeValue().getSomethingElse().returnsSomething();
```

Comment: I would give the same advice as for `auto` in c++, only use this when you're sure there won't be conflicts (and abuse it for long types, we know our map entries). If you know the type (and it's not very long), you should use it.

Comment: You _can_ use it for non-denotable types.

Comment: FWIW I don't like it either, so my answer would be **you shouldn't use it**. You should always know the type as far as I'm concerned, and not writing it is arguably bad for readability. That and there's *many* more useful things that could be added to Java on a language level. That said, I'm an old fuddy duddy when it comes to these things, and there will clearly be others that disagree, so this really is just opinion based without a clear answer, and not on topic here.

Comment: *Style Guidelines for Local Variable Type Inference:* http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html

Comment: There are plenty of circumstances where type inference makes code _more_ readable.  Of course, if you write bad code (poorly chosen variable names, super-long methods, etc), then leaving out type information might make your bad code even worse.  So, write good code, and use it where it helps.

Comment: Are you saying that if you _could_ use `var` for all the types you wanted, that you would then write the given example code with no qualms about it?  I'd suggest that unless it were blindingly obvious in context, the example code is likely to be a bad choice with any kind of type inference in any language, regardless of specific mechanics.

Comment: IMO it adds ambiguity to code. So NO. For instance, `var var = 10`, the var here is inferred as a long.

Answer (score 28):

Though this is probably primarily opinion-based, I'd say: **No, it is not evil.**

The `var` keyword is only allowed when the type of the variable is already clear at compile-time. Also, it will generate the same bytecode, so there is nothing to fear.

In some cases like `null`, `var` is not allowed.   This doesn't make it evil, but rather good. If this was not the case, Java would not be statically typed anymore.  (Note, however, it *is* allowed in most of the cases you've listed.)

Also I don't see any problem with your example. Since your `.returnsSomething()` would rather be something like `.getPerson()` in the real world, it would be clear to the reader that `var` is a Person.

Comment: `null` is the *only* case among the OP’s list which doesn’t work. And even for that case, I don’t see how supporting it, e.g. by always inferring `Object` for `null`, would imply that “Java would not be statically typed anymore”.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, it might be valid to assume that `getPerson()` returns a `Person`, but it doesn’t matter. Note how the OP is willing to write an expression like `someObj.getSomeValue().getSomethingElse().returnsSomething()` without knowing, what type `getSomeValue()` or `getSomethingElse()` are returning. That’s not different to writing `var x = someObj.getSomeValue(); var y = x.getSomethingElse(); y.returnsSomething()`…

Comment: getPerson() . That could be the DTO or the JPA entity ?

Comment: Even in the Java code itself you have poorly chosen names. `var buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: It's only clear to the compiler. It's no longer clear to the reader without either inspecting the code in some kind of IDE or knowing all the APIs involved. The code is simply less readable in many situations.

Comment: https://medium.com/@spextreme/java-var-should-be-a-code-smell-17af0be79646